# undefined local variable or method `stimulus_include_tags'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs

I'm running into issues when trying to upgrade:

```
~/work/hotwire-rails-demo-chat main* 9s
❯ ./bin/rails server
Calling `DidYouMean::SPELL_CHECKERS.merge!(error_name => spell_checker)' has been deprecated. Please call `DidYouMean.correct_error(error_name, spell_checker)' instead.
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.4.3 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 6.2.2 (ruby 3.2.2-p53) ("Speaking of Now")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 103015
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on http://[::1]:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-04-18 09:48:59 -0700
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Pluck (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by RoomsController#index as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering rooms/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Room Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "rooms".* FROM "rooms"
  ↳ app/views/rooms/index.html.erb:14
  Rendered rooms/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 17.4ms | Allocations: 1768)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 481.5ms | Allocations: 68851)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 514ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 75379)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `stimulus_include_tags' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000000c8c8>):
     9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    10:     <%= yield :head %>
    11:     <%= turbo_include_tags %>
    12:     <%= stimulus_include_tags %>
    13:   </head>
    14:
    15:   <body>

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12
```

I followed the [manual stimulus-rails install instruction here](https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails/#installing-manually), but still get the above error. I didn't see any stackoverflow questions similar to this one.

Comment: Are you using import maps or jsbundling-rails?